# Ubuntu 18.04 dedicated nvidia graphics card fails when lifting lid

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I am working with a linux laptop. It has an integrated and dedicated gpu, but currently only uses the dedicated nvidia gpu. While I would love to have it dynamically switch between integrated and dedicated, that is a problem for another day.

Sometimes, when I shut the lid and then open it the screen is white with colored blacks scattered throughout.  This happens regardless if I logout or put the laptop to sleep.

The solution is to turn the device off and then turn it back on.

Since it is only running on the dedicated gpu, the battery life isn't all that great, but this "feature" means that I have to save everything or pause everything prior to leaving the laptop, which is very inconvenient.

Any ideas?

---

Settings > Details > About

```
Processor Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU
Graphics GeForce GTX 1070 with MaxQ Design/PCIe/SSE2
GNOME 3.28.2
OS type 64 bit
```

Software & Updates > Additional Drivers

```
NVIDIA Corporation: GP104M [GeForce GTX 1070 Mobile] (GeForce GTX 1070 Max-Q)
[x] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-415 (open-source)
[ ] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-396 (open-source)
[ ] Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-410 (open-source)
[ ] Using X. Org X server - Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)
```

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia graphics drivers? If so, which version? If not, why not?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia well the gpu is already working... so I figured it was fine... but the "recommend" is nvidia-driver-415 but install nvidia-415 doesn't work and under software & updates > additional drivers, I have a few driver "NVIDIA driver metapackage"...

Comment: Go to Nvidia.com and search - search only, do NOT install from there - the recommended driver version(s) for your specific card. Then install it with Additional Drivers (you may need to select one "metapackage"; I had to do that after a 16.04 -> 18:04 release upgrade).  *I figured it was fine*... Yes, partially supported by the open-source driver (outputs video) but performance is subpar and then other issues like the one you're now familiar with. Also the Nvidia proprietary drivers are required to enable switching.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia switching from meta package 410 to 425 downloaded something and now I have prime profile. When I have dedicated you active, will this be sufficient to “fix” the lid issue?

Comment: Yes, hopefully. I never had problem with suspension when using the recommended Nvidia drivers but had occasionally seen it happen the way you describe with `nouveau`.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia alas, I did this, rebooted, closed the lid, opened the lid and got the same :’(

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all that information you just posted as comments and also please include your hardware info/specifications. And I hope your Ubuntu has been installed in the correct mode (UEFI mode), legacy mode with modern hardware, especially dual or hybrid graphics is absolutely NOT recommended.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I provided additional information